# Is .vsmdi file is supported in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, automated-tests, test-project

We are migrating our source code from VS 2012 to VS 2017. Our code is combination of both managed (c#) and native (c++). We also had test projects to test our implementation. As part of this, we have managed "MyProjectTest.vsmdi" file.

Since we are migrating entire solution, I wanted to know if we need to change anything in .vsmdi file as well?

If yes,
please let me know what changes are needed.

Refer below sample data:

```
<TestLink id="536876ba-89b5-4188-07c2-3003f6d95f1e" name="Duplicate_Failure" storage="commandline\tests\bin\x86\debug\commandline.tests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Do we need to change `Version tag here` ?

With Best Regards,

Tausifahamad